# Azure tables rest api authorization

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I'm trying to use azure rest api from powershell but stuck with authorization part. Used to generate signature using this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx

Script:

```
$StorageAccount = "account"
$Key = "key"

$sharedKey = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Key)
$date = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("R")

$resource = "/test()?`$top" # also tried /test() /test /test()?`$top=1
$stringToSign = "$date`n/$StorageAccount$resource"
$hasher = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hasher.Key = $sharedKey

$signedSignature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hasher.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign)))

$authHeader = "SharedKeyLite ${StorageAccount}:$signedSignature"

$headers = @{"x-ms-date"=$date
            "Authorization"=$authHeader
            "Accept"="application/atom+xml"}

try {
    $tables = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$StorageAccount.table.core.windows.net/test()?`$top=1" -Headers $headers |% {
        $_.content.properties.tablename
    }
} catch [Exception] {
    $_
}
```

I was able to list tables (**/tables**) but when I try to execute some odata requests (**/test()?$top=1** here) I am getting authorization error.

Answer (score 2):

I copy your code and try it at my end. It works fine.

Here are somethings I want to point out.

1. For "Query Entities", you should use `$resource = "/test()"`, and `$resource = "/test"` is for "Insert Entity". `$resource = "/test()?$top"` and `$resource = "/test()?$top=1"` are not correct.
2. Make sure your `$Key` is correct. Since you have use this key for creating the table, I don't think this is the case.
3. Make sure there is at least one row in your table.

Comment: Thanks for reply! The `$Key` is a primary key from my storage account. When I set $resource to be `/test()` a request fails with auth error `Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.`

Comment: I also created new table using `$key` though I continue getting auth error :(

Comment: Your script is correct. Try your storage account and key with Azure Storage Explorer. If not working, regenerate your key.